# Error when using predict() on a randomForest object trained with caret's train() using formula

Tags: r, formula, random-forest, r-caret, predict

Using R 3.2.0 with caret 6.0-41 and randomForest 4.6-10 on a 64-bit Linux machine.

When trying to use the `predict()` method on a `randomForest` object trained with the `train()` function from the `caret` package using a formula, the function returns an error.
When training via `randomForest()` and/or using `x=` and `y=` rather than a formula, it all runs smoothly.

Here is a working example:

```
library(randomForest)
library(caret)

data(imports85)
imp85     <- imports85[, c("stroke", "price", "fuelType", "numOfDoors")]
imp85     <- imp85[complete.cases(imp85), ]
imp85[]   <- lapply(imp85, function(x) if (is.factor(x)) x[,drop=TRUE] else x) ## Drop empty levels for factors.

modRf1  <- randomForest(numOfDoors~., data=imp85)
caretRf <- train( numOfDoors~., data=imp85, method = "rf" )
modRf2  <- caretRf$finalModel
modRf3  <- randomForest(x=imp85[,c("stroke", "price", "fuelType")], y=imp85[, "numOfDoors"])
caretRf <- train(x=imp85[,c("stroke", "price", "fuelType")], y=imp85[, "numOfDoors"], method = "rf")
modRf4  <- caretRf$finalModel

p1      <- predict(modRf1, newdata=imp85)
p2      <- predict(modRf2, newdata=imp85)
p3      <- predict(modRf3, newdata=imp85)
p4      <- predict(modRf4, newdata=imp85)
```

Among the last 4 lines, only the second one `p2 <- predict(modRf2, newdata=imp85)` returns the following error:

```
Error in predict.randomForest(modRf2, newdata = imp85) : 
variables in the training data missing in newdata
```

It seems that the reason for this error is that the `predict.randomForest` method uses `rownames(object$importance)` to determine the name of the variables used to train the random forest `object`. And when looking at

```
rownames(modRf1$importance)
rownames(modRf2$importance)
rownames(modRf3$importance)
rownames(modRf4$importance)
```

We see:

```
[1] "stroke"   "price"    "fuelType"
[1] "stroke"   "price"    "fuelTypegas"
[1] "stroke"   "price"    "fuelType"
[1] "stroke"   "price"    "fuelType"
```

So somehow, when using the `caret` `train()` function with a formula changes the name of the (factor) variables in the `importance` field of the `randomForest` object.

Is it really an inconsistency between the formula and and non-formula version of the caret `train()` function? Or am I missing something?

Comment: `modRf3  <- randomForest(x=dataTrain[,c("stroke", "price", "fuelType")], y=dataTrain[, "numOfDoors"], data=imp85)
Error in randomForest(x = dataTrain[, c("stroke", "price", "fuelType")],  : 
  object 'dataTrain' not found`

Comment: As pointed out, you did not define `dataTrain` in your example which means the problem is not [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It's not easy to help you if we can't run the code and get the same results as you.

Comment: My bad, `dataTrain` should have been `imp85`, I edited the code in the original question. I also removed the option `data=imp85` in the call where `x`  and `y` are explicitly mentioned as there is no use for it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

First, **almost never** use the `$finalModel` object for prediction. Use `predict.train`. This is one good example of why.

There is some inconsistency between how some functions (including `randomForest` and `train`) handle dummy variables. Most functions in R that use the formula method will convert factor predictors to dummy variables because their models require numerical representations of the data. The exceptions to this are tree- and rule-based models (that can split on categorical predictors), naive Bayes, and a few others.

So `randomForest` will *not* create dummy variables when you use `randomForest(y ~ ., data = dat)` but `train` (and most others) will using a call like `train(y ~ ., data = dat)`.

The error occurs because `fuelType` is a factor. The dummy variables created by `train` don't have the same names so `predict.randomForest` can't find them.

Using the non-formula method with `train` will pass the factor predictors to `randomForest` and everything will work.

**TL;DR**

Use the non-formula method with `train` if you want the same levels **or** use `predict.train`

Comment: I unfortunately don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer, but you answered perfectly my question. I had been wondering for all those functions that allow to use formula, if there was a difference in the way the data was treated between the formula and non-formula versions of the function call. Now I know! For the use of `$finalModel`, I agree that it's generally not a good idea to use it. Here I just wanted to compare the outcome of the `caret` and `randomForest` methods.

Comment: What do you mean by "use the non-formula method"?

Answer (score 0):

There can be two reasons why you get this error.

**1.** The categories of the categorical variables in the train and test sets don't match. To check that, you can run something like the following.

Well, first of all, it is good practice to keep the independent variables/features in a list. Say that list is "vars". And say, you separated "Data" into "Train" and "Test". Let's go:

> ```
> for (v in vars){
>   if (class(Data[,v]) == 'factor'){
>     print(v)
>     # print(levels(Train[,v])) 
>     # print(levels(Test[,v]))
>     print(all.equal(levels(Train[,v]) , levels(Test[,v])))
>   }  
> }
> ```

Once you find the non-matching categorical variables, you can go back, and impose the categories of Test data onto Train data, and then re-build your model. In a loop similar to above, for each nonMatchingVar, you can do

> ```
> levels(Test$nonMatchingVar) <- levels(Train$nonMatchingVar)
> ```

**2.** A silly one. If you accidentally leave the dependent variable in the set of independent variables, you may run into this error message. I have done that mistake. Solution: Just be more careful.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to explicitly code the testing data using `model.matrix`, e.g.

```
p2 <- predict(modRf2, newdata=model.matrix(~., imp85))
```