# r caret finalModel parameter / predict with pre-processing in a repeatedcv for multiple models

Tags: r, parameters, prediction, r-caret

I am confused about how to predict on new data after caret model tuning. First it sounds easy; just tune a model and use the model$finalModel, but there are some problems.

> **5.5.1 Pre-Processing Options**
>
> These processing steps would be applied during any predictions
>   generated using predict.train, extractPrediction or extractProbs (see
>   details later in this document). The pre-processing **would not be
>   applied to predictions** that directly use the object$finalModel object. [link](https://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#customizing-the-tuning-process)

As you can read here (its the creator of the package)

> In other words, any pre-processing that you ask for is done to the training set prior to running randomForest. It also applied the same pre-processing to any data that you predict on (using predict(RFFit, testSet)). **If you use the finalModel** object, you are using predict.randomForest instead of predict.train and **none of the pre-processing is done** before prediction. [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81609/whether-preprocessing-is-needed-before-prediction-using-finalmodel-of-randomfore)

And next

> **First, almost never use the $finalModel object for prediction. Use predict.train. This is one good example of why.**
>
> There is some inconsistency between how some functions (including randomForest and train) handle dummy variables. Most functions in R that use the formula method will convert factor predictors to dummy variables because their models require numerical representations of the data. The exceptions to this are tree- and rule-based models (that can split on categorical predictors), naive Bayes, and a few others. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097730/error-when-using-predict-on-a-randomforest-object-trained-with-carets-train)

In the following [example see "2. Create A Standalone Model"](http://machinelearningmastery.com/finalize-machine-learning-models-in-r/) (no pre-processing) you can see how we can solve this, he builds a complete new "standalone model" and it is used to predict. It's easy to add pre-processing here again.

```
....
# create standalone model using all training data
set.seed(7)
finalModel <- randomForest(Class~., training, mtry=2, ntree=2000)
# make a predictions on "new data" using the final model
final_predictions <- predict(finalModel, validation[,1:60])
confusionMatrix(final_predictions, validation$Class)
```

BUT I don't want to change my code every time or manually extract and insert the parameter from object$finalModel, that's why I am using caret?

I want to use the object$finalModel or at least extract its parameter grid, BUT for multiple models (i.e. gbm,knn,...)

**::: linux-gnu R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) ::: Single Candle :::**

```
r_get_best <- function(.mth="gbm") {

    library(caret)
    library(mlbench)
    library(randomForest)

    data(Sonar)
    idx <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class,p=0.80,list=F)
    trn <- Sonar[idx,]
    tst <- Sonar[-idx,]

    # settings
    prp <- c("center","scale")
    tcl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv",number=3,repeats=3,preProcOptions=prp,verboseIter=F)

    # train model(.mth)
    set.seed(7)
    fit <- train(Class~.,data=trn,method=.mth,metric="Accuracy",preProcess=prp,trControl=tcl)
    print(fit)
    print("")
    print("----- final model -----")
    print(fit$finalModel)

    # i can get the result, but this way i have to construct a new grid + re-train a new final model
    frs <- fit$results[which.max(fit$results[,fit$metric]),]
    print("")
    print("----- final model extracted -----")
    print(frs)

    # use fit$finalModel OR fit$bestTune ???
    fml <- NULL # ??????????

    # make test prediction on UNSEEN tst data using the final model
    # prd <- predict(fml,tst[,-ncol(tst)])

    # check the quality
    # cfm <- confusionMatrix(prd,tst$Class)
    # print("")
    # print(cfm)

    return(fml)

}

> r_get_best("gbm")
```

I can't use predict(model$finalModel).  I also can't use predict.train() because I am using the formula interface + pre-processing.

So the question is, how can I use the object$finalModel or extract its parameter setup for multiple methods ="gbm,knn,rf,..." to predict on new (unseen) data, even when I am using formula interface + pre-processing + maybe cross-validation before?

Or is it the best way to use the non-formula interface?

**Shame on me, one part of the question is solved:**
    The final values used for the model were n.trees = 150,
    interaction.depth = 2, shrinkage = 0.1 and n.minobsinnode = 10.

```
> Tuned Parameters can be accessed through model$bestTune

 n.trees interaction.depth shrinkage n.minobsinnode
 150               2         0.1             10
```

But is this the way to go, create a new model and train it on all the data again?