# randomForest in R is including the class label as a feature prevents classifier from predicting on new dataset

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, random-forest

So I have two datasets, og.data and newdata.df.  I have matched their features and I want to use a feature from og.data to train a model so I can identify cases of this class in newdata.df.  I am using the randomForest package in R documentation for it is here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf

```
split <- sample.split(og.data$class_label, SplitRatio = 0.7)

training_set = subset(og.data$class_label, split == TRUE)
test_set = subset(og.data$class_label, split == FALSE)

rf.classifier.object = randomForest(x = training_set[-1],
                                          y = training_set$Engramcell,
                                          ntree = 500)
```

I then use the test set to calculate the AUC, visualize ROC, precision, recall etc etc.
I do that using prediction probability generated like so...

```
predictions.df <- as.data.frame(predict(rf.classifier.object,
                                            test_set,
                                            type = "prob")
                                    )
```

All is good I proceed to try to use the classifier I've trained on new data and now I am encountering a problem because the new data does not contain the feature class label.  Whihc is annoying as the entire purpose of training the classifier to to label this newdata.

```
predictions.df <- as.data.frame(predict(rf.classifier.object,
                                            newdata.df,
                                            type = "prob")
                                    )
```

Please note the error has different variable names simply because I changed the code to make it more general for readability.

```
Error in predict.randomForest(rf.classifier.object, newdata.df,  : 
  variables in the training data missing in newdata
```

As per [this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097730/error-when-using-predict-on-a-randomforest-object-trained-with-carets-train) `predict.randomForest()`, called here as `predict()`, uses rownames of feature importance to make its precitions.  And when I checked with a search of the feature names I find that it is infact the class label preventing me from making the test as I show bellow.

```
# > rownames(rf.classifier.object$importance)[!(rownames(rf.classifier.object$importance) %in% colnames(newdata) )]  
# [1] "class_label"
```

It is not clear to me what I should change in my script so that the classifier can be used on other data than the testing set.  I have followed the instructions exactly this seems like a bad design choice to have made the function this way.  The class label should not be used for calculating feature importance at all and should not even be considered a feature imo.